# Okta social authentication with angular and spring

Tags: spring, angular, okta

I have downloaded that example:

https://github.com/mraible/okta-spring-boot-angular-example

it works fine but I have no clue how to to authenticate with facebook or microsoft account? Is there any working example with that identity providers or can someone tell me what to do?

I have found example at okta website how to configure that in dashboard and at microsoft developer account but I don't know how to redirect from my webpage to site where I can sign in using microsoft account not okta account.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hey Adam. That's a pretty old example, I'm not even sure there's a blog post to go with it. I'd recommend checking out our [oktadeveloper Angular examples](https://github.com/oktadeveloper?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=*angular-*example&type=&language=). Most of these projects have associated blog posts.

Answer (score 1):

Once you configure IDP using [this](https://developer.okta.com/authentication-guide/social-login/). At the end, they give you options for integration. For example, if you are looking to integrate Facebook, at the end of the guide they give you an html [button](https://developer.okta.com/authentication-guide/social-login/facebook#using-facebook-for-login) you integrate with your apps or if you are using Okta's sign-in widget. It shows how to do so.